# How to create template element dynamically with DOM operations

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component

I like to create a HTML template element dynamically with JavaScript DOM operations.
Something like this:

```js
const template = document.createElement("template")

const div = document.createElement("div")

template.append(div)
```

However, when using `append` the div container won't be available in the templates `content` property.
Instead, you have to use `innerHTML` like this:

```js
const template = document.createElement("template")

template.innerHTML = "<div></div>"
```

This does work because `innerHTML` has a special behavior implemented for template tags (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#Operational_details).

However, `innerHTML` comes with some downsides and so the question is: How do you use template tag with content created with `document.createElement`?

One aspect here is that some JavaScript frameworks (i.e. angular and react) do use `document.createElement` internally to create the DOM tree. This makes it nearly impossible to use the template tag with these frameworks.

As an author of a web component that uses the template tag I'd like to support framework users but at the moment I don't see any way of doing so and I'm starting to thinking about removing the template tag altogether. On the other hand I can't imagine that using `innerHTML` is the only way here and that the authors of the web component standards haven't thought about this so there must be something I'm overlooking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You are doing:**

```
  const template = document.createElement("template");
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  template.appendChild(div);
```

**You should do:**

```
  const template = document.createElement("template");
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  template.content.appendChild(div);
```

**Note** You might as well do **append** here, you are not using the return value.
And append can take TextNodes and multiple parameters:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: It does work with appending to `content`. But in the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-template-element) you can read: "It is also possible, as a result of DOM manipulation, for a template element to contain Text nodes and element nodes; however, having any is a violation of the template element's content model, since its content model is defined as nothing.". It sounds as if this is not the expected approach.

Comment: That note is about the ``template.append`` scenario. It is possible to add Nodes, but **that** is the violation